# Getting a file writer to write the same thing to a html file that it does to the console?

Tags: java, html

I'm going to do this question in three sections: The first will be explaining what my code currently does, the second explaining what I wish to do and the third will be my code.

My code currently selects a text file then asks the user whether they wish for it to be output in html or plaintext. If the user selects html then it is supposed to write the information into a html file that is then rendered.

What I want to do is make it so that this output will be displayed in the manner that I want it to, I have it working for the plaintext version but when I run the html version I encounter problems where it won't do it correctly.

```
private static void processhtml(String UserFile) throws FileNotFoundException {
      String hteam;
        String ateam;
        int hscore;
        int ascore;
        int totgoals = 0;
        int gamesplayed = 0;
        int gs = 0;
        int gc = 0;
        int w = 0;
        int d = 0;
        int l = 0;
        String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");//This will retrieve line separator dependent on OS.

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader(UserFile))).useDelimiter("\\s*:\\s*|\\s*\\n\\s*");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the name of the team you want the results for");
        String input = scanner.nextLine();


        int count=0;
        String line="";
        String[] words=new String[40];
        try{
             String fileName="test"+count+".html";
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileName, "UTF-8");
          while (s.hasNext()) {


              line =s.next();
                  words = line.split("\\s*:\\s*");

                  for(int i=0;i<words.length;i++){
                      writer.println(input + newLine + "--------------------------" + newLine + "Games played: " + gamesplayed +   newLine + "Games Won: " + w + newLine + "Games Drawn: " + d + newLine + "Games Lost: " + l + newLine + "Goals For: " + gs + newLine + "Goals Against: " + gc);   
;
                }



        }
          writer.close();
            writer.flush();

        }catch(Exception e){

        e.printStackTrace();
        }


            if(verifyFormat(words)) {
                hteam = words[0];       // read the home team
                ateam = words[1];       // read the away team
                hscore = Integer.parseInt(words[2]);       //read the home team score
                totgoals = totgoals + hscore;
                ascore = Integer.parseInt(words[3]);       //read the away team score
                totgoals = totgoals + ascore;

                 if ( input.equalsIgnoreCase(hteam)){
                     gamesplayed = gamesplayed + 1;
                     gs = gs + hscore;
                     gc = gc + ascore;
                     if (hscore > ascore)
                         w = w + 1;
                     else if (ascore > hscore)
                         l = l + 1;
                     else
                         d = d + 1;
                 }
                 else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(ateam)){
                     gamesplayed = gamesplayed + 1;
                     gs = gs + ascore;
                     gc = gc + hscore;
                     if (hscore < ascore)
                         w = w + 1;
                     else if (ascore < hscore)
                         l = l + 1;
                     else
                         d = d + 1;
                 }


                //output the data from the file in the format requested

            }

        }
```

This is the code I currently have to try and make the html but it doesn't work.

```
System.out.println(input + newLine + "--------------------------" + newLine + "Games played: " + gamesplayed +   newLine + "Games Won: " + w + newLine + "Games Drawn: " + d + newLine + "Games Lost: " + l + newLine + "Goals For: " + gs + newLine + "Goals Against: " + gc);
```

and this is the code that I use for the output for the plaintext version which does work.

Comment: For one, a line break in plain text and a line break in html are completely different. Linux line break: `\n` Html line break: `<br>`. I think this will reveal the larger problem when trying to go from plain text to html.

Comment: @JonnyHenly I know html I'm not sure how to format it so that a java file will output into a html file whilst in a loop

Comment: `String fileName="test"+count+".html";` Is it not outputting to a `.html` currently?

Comment: @JonnyHenly it is but I can't figure out how to format it in the way that I wish because whenever I try it doesn't work

Comment: @JonnyHenly What I mean by this is that when I run it rather than getting the correct results at all it displays completely different ones than expected and this is very confusing to me.

Comment: Please edit your question adding the output you're currently receiving and what you're expecting to receive.